# Remote debugging web service hosted by Cassini

Tags: web-services, debugging, cassini

Is there any way to remote debug a web service on my local machine that is being hosted by Cassini?

ie On my local machine I can browse to http:// localhost:1234/webservice, but I cannot go to another machine and access http:// ip_address_of_my_machine:1234/webservice.

Is there a way?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find cassini doesn't allow remote connections. Any reason you can't run it from your IIS webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Use Fiddler!

> Fiddler can operate as a "reverse proxy" which means that it can forward inbound requests to a different port or web server.
>
> Step #0
>   Before either of the following options will work, you must enable other computers to connect to Fiddler. To do so, click Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections and tick the "Allow remote computers to connect" checkbox. Then close Fiddler.
>
> Option #1: Configure Fiddler as a Reverse-Proxy
>   Fiddler can be configured so that any traffic sent to http://127.0.0.1:8888 is automatically sent to a different port on the same machine.  To set this configuration:
>
> Start REGEDIT 
>   Create a new DWORD named ReverseProxyForPort inside HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2. 
>   Set the DWORD to the local port you'd like to re-route inbound traffic to (generally port 80 for a standard HTTP server) 
>   Restart Fiddler 
>   Navigate your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8888

Source: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

Answer (score 0):

And now in IIS7.5 you can:
[Configure IIS Express for external access to VS2010 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project)