# how to access cassini server remotely in LAN for demo?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When Start Visual studio and run a silverlight application, VS will start a cassini server on specific port, like:

http://localhost:3107/MyApp.aspx

This is convenience for developer for testing.

Then I want to access this web app from another computer in local LAN for live demo purpose like:

http://mycomputername:3107/MyApp.aspx

but I failed. How to make it working?

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304116/remote-debugging-web-service-hosted-by-cassini

Comment: There might be a dup out there, but that isn't it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your site to IIS. Cassini is meant for development only and doesn't allow remote connections.

A simpler solution would just be to RDP into your development machine while doing the demo.

Answer (score 3):

Use Fiddler!

> Fiddler can operate as a "reverse proxy" which means that it can forward inbound requests to a different port or web server.
>
> Step #0 Before either of the following options will work, you must enable other computers to connect to Fiddler. To do so, click Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections and tick the "Allow remote computers to connect" checkbox. Then close Fiddler.
>
> Option #1: Configure Fiddler as a Reverse-Proxy Fiddler can be configured so that any traffic sent to http://127.0.0.1:8888 is automatically sent to a different port on the same machine. To set this configuration:
>
> Start REGEDIT Create a new DWORD named ReverseProxyForPort inside HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fiddler2. Set the DWORD to the local port you'd like to re-route inbound traffic to (generally port 80 for a standard HTTP server) Restart Fiddler Navigate your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8888

Source: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/reverseproxy.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try using [UltiDev Cassini Web Server](http://ultidev.com/Products/Cassini/index.htm). I'v used it my self to create web services and its very good and stable.

Answer (score 0):

Another (hacky) option would be to use sshd or other proxy to create a tunnel on the machine to the local port. But @Bob has it right - Cassini is designed for local access only.