# invoking a web service from another machine

Tags: c#, web-services

this is my question:
i need to invoke a web service hosted on HostA from a web browser on HostB.
i create a web service on HostA, i started it with F5 and this is the local url:

```
http://localhost:55432/Service1.svc
```

On HostB, i used the same url changing localhost with the HostA IP (pingable).
But it doesn't work. The Page return a `"Unable To Connect to IP-Address".`

i don't think it's a code problem, but it look like a connection/security problem.
Thanks for helps.

Comment: Firewall blocking the port on HostA?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Visual Studio web servers (Cassini for older implementations, IIS express for newer implementations) do not even bind to your network adapter's IP address, instead only binding to localhost. So, by default, they do not accept remote connections.

If you're using Cassini, you can refer to [how to access cassini server remotely in LAN for demo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533574/) for more information.

IIS express is handled differently, as evidenced in [IIS Express enable external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616).