# Debugging ASP.NET MVC project in VS2010 and accessing on networked computers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I'm wondering if it's possible to allow users on my local network to connect to an ASP.NET MVC 3 app I'm running through VS2010 on my local PC. The purpose is to let others test during some rapid application development without deploying to a server.

By default, the port seems to be blocked. Is there a setting in VS2010 or IIS Express that I can change to allow access to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default VS sets localhost bindings in applicationhost.config file (%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config), so you cannot access it from other machines.

To access your site from other machines,

1. you need to update your site bindings (in applicationhost.config file) and add a site binding with your machinename
2. Run VS as administrator
3. If firewall is blocking your port, unblock it

Following link may help you
[Configure IIS Express for external access to VS2010 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project/5438322#5438322)