# Remote Machine Debugging in Visual Studio 2012 with Metro and WCF

Tags: wcf, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug my Metro application on a tablet from my desktop, however when it boots up and tries to get data from my wcf service i get this error:

An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost:39855/MyService.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I'd assume that this is because the service is hosted on my desktop in iis express, and the tablet app is trying to look for the service at localhost which wouldn't be where the service is hosted, it would have to be the ip of my desktop or something. But how would i change my service in Visual studio to be hosted at my ip instead of localhost? I have disabled both firewalls so there should be nothing causing problems in that regard.

My experience with WCF is pretty limited :(

Or do i have to set up IIS, deploy my service on my local machine, and point the tablet to that address?

Answer (score 0):

Hosting the service in iis express should be fine, but you have to modify the client (the tablet app) to point to your host machine explicitly (using the IP or the network host name of the machine). You can do that either by modifying the configuration file for the app or by creating the client binding in code, specifying the host.

Comment: I did some more research and did the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project/5438322#5438322, I am able to browse the service from the tablet in the browser, and I changed the app to point to my desktop IP, however I still get the same error It just says there was no endpoint listening at http://[myip]:39855. If i look at the inner exception I see a SocketErrorCode of 10013/Access Denied.