# Is there a way I can avoid iisexpress startup delays when it loads DLLs every time I do a build?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-express

I am using VS2010 and IIS Express. When I do a build there are long delays while all the dlls load up. On my rather slow machine it's usually 3-4 minutes.

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1100) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
The thread '<No Name>' (0xc18) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration.Install\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.Install.dll'
The thread '<No Name>' (0xdf0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.Design.dll'
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 500 : Role instance status check starting
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Verbose: 502 : Role instance status check succeeded: Ready
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\977c2a31\7c0f0d28\App_Web_aohydr2s.dll', Symbols loaded.
The thread '<No Name>' (0xe38) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Is there some way I could preload these or leave IIS running. The Microsoft ones don't change from one week to another but it takes a few minutes of me watching them load in the output window every time I make a small change to my MVC C# code and want to check out the changes with a build and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to configure debugging to run on local IIS:
[image: Web project configuration]

Just make sure you have the same radio buttons selected in your configuration.
And you'll need to create a web-site in your IIS: 
[image: IIS configuration]

And add another line to your Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       amv.local
```

This way every time you start debugging, you will not need to start a new page. And you will not need to remember what port you have assigned to your debug site.

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting IIS Express yourself and have it act like IIS. So configure it to run and then in your web project, tell it you are using IIS, but configure for the details you setup IIS Express.

Now just keep in mind you'll have to have IIS express run in the same directory you develop in, so that you don't have to deploy every time to see your changes.

Check out this post too: [Configure IIS Express for external access to VS2010 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project)