# 400 bad request when access ASP.net web api via computer name on IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting a 400 bad request error message when accessing an ASP.net web api via a url that uses the computer name. When I use localhost it works fine.
I'm using the iisExpress for visual studio 2012.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try using the FQDN or the IP Address?

Comment: are you using iis or iis express to host the application?

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking time to read and respond. I'm using iis express and computer name but not fully qualified. In my hosts file I have my computer name set to 127.0.0.1. I will try using the fully qualified name to see if it helps

Comment: I tried it with the fully qualified domain name added to my computer name and still get the same error. The reason why I need to use the computer name instead of localhost is that I want to trace it with fiddler. Fiddler will not work with localhost. When I use my computer name, I am able to get fiddler to log but then I get the error "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid." from the ASP.net web api.

Comment: How is the site in IIS Express configured?  Does it expect a hostname when requests are sent to it?

Comment: I'm new to ASP.net Web api and not sure where I should look for the url configuration on the site. I'm using the ValueController that inherits from ApiController. Is there a way to specify the url in the web.config?

Comment: I found the answer to this from another post on here. I had to update my IISExpress' applicationhost.config file and add a binding with my computer name on it. The link to the other post is here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer to this from another post on here. I had to update my IISExpress' applicationhost.config file and add a binding with my computer name on it.

The link to the other post is here: [Configure IIS Express for external access to VS2010 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to change configurations, you can use our free VS extension called Conveyor

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Comment: @user3419036 no, it is free.  The premium version is $30 that's all.