# Access localhost on windows 7 VMWare Fusion

Tags: .net, servicestack, virtual-machine, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a .Net API service in Windows 7 box and try to debug API from my Mac OS, however, I am not able to hit the API through the port (3345). I used ipconfig to find out my windows7 IP address, and then try to access it through (address:port), and it never connects.

Anything I need to do on VMFusion to allow me hit the .Net API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Windows 7 box doesn't have the firewall on, or make an exception to allow a connection on your port.  The default settings will block that port.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this a while back and was unsuccessful after several hours on trying. I gave up as iis would not run properly on my machine. You can search on SO and find others asking the same question. I do know that you have to use iis express in vstudio  and then edit the iis config file to allow access from any host. Try this question, [Configure IIS Express for external access to VS2010 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project)