# How to debug calls to ASP.NET web api in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a Mobile application that talks to a web api which I am also developing.

I am at the stage now where I need the phone to start communicating to the web api, However I have noticed that when I click RUN in visual studio, I can only access the site on localhost.

This obviously is an issue as the mobile device I'm testing on is connected to the WIFI Network which my pc is also connected to.

How can I enable remote access?

Do I have to install IIS and run the api it on the IIS server? If so, then how do I debug?

Im running win 8.1 64bit VS 2013

Comment: Sorry, why is it obvious that it's an issue that your phone is connected to the WIFI network?  What may be obvious to you isn't to us, since we don't know what your network topology is.  However, have you tried testing your app with one of the Mobile Emulators running on your local PC?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I have tried in emulator. But Localhost refers to the mobile device being emulated and not the PC / Host . If I try access the site via IP rather than Localhost even on host pc it gives and error.

Comment: @Zapnologica - are you using IIS express?  If so, you need to configure it for external access.  It's typically easier to configure IIS on your local computer instead.

Comment: I have tried everything, It will not for the life of me work. I have followed 6 or 7 web tutorials and it dont work for me. I either get 503 error or VS wont run.