# Binding IISExpress to IP Address Failing

Tags: iis, iis-express

I've had this working on the same Windows box in Win8 Win8.1 and Win10.  Yesterday I performed the Threshold 2 upgrade to Windows 10 and now I can't  launch my API in IISExpress.

The bindings are setup like this:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51258:jamhq" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51258:192.168.0.8" />
```

I've triple checked all my `netsh` settings and at the moment Windows Firewall is completely disabled whilst I troubleshoot.

Every time I try to launch this I'm now presented with an error like this:

```
Failed to register URL "http://192.168.0.8:51258/" for site "<name>" application "/"
Error Description: The Network location cannot be reached.
For more information ... (0x800704d0)
```

I can ping this IP (obviously since I'm pinging myself), I can ping this location from my other machines / devices.

It seems like some extremely low level network setting has been changed.

Has anyone seen this problem or have a solution?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So, this is something that might help others in the future, I've been going round and round on this problem today and have just fixed the issue.

It appears that the update removes IP addresses that the http.sys is listening on.  So when executing:

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

The only entry I had after the update was:

```
::
```

So executing:

```
netsh http add iplisten 192.168.0.8
```

Bingo, everything is now working again.

Comment: Did you do anything special to your network setup? I tried setting this up again, but still can't access my site via the local IP from any of my other machines/devices.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out using this article: http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer

Comment: What fixed it for you?

Comment: I didn't do anything in particular to the network setup other than fixing the missing IP Listening entry using the commands in the answer.

Comment: The two ```netsh``` commands in the second part of the article: 1) ```netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.42:58938/ user=everyone``` 2) ```netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=58938 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow``` Of course corrected the IPs, ports and the firewall rule name to correspond to my own setup.

Comment: Ahhh ok.  Yes, what confused me so much was that I had already done all that a long time ago.  I've never seen an update blat the host IP address as a listening address.  I've reported that to MS.

Comment: This happened to me after using the Azure functions tooling to test locally and this solved my issue.  Thank you

Comment: Thanks. This command resolved my problem perfectly.

"netsh http add iplisten 192.168.x.xxx"

Comment: In my case, IIS Express was complaining that "network location cannot be reached" for 127.0.0.1:60000. `netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1:60000` resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by enable it globally thru my network, not only in specific IP.

From CMD(need to run as admin)

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0
```

Inside project applicationhost.config I put the binding globally as below:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":51258:" />
```

This will make your application can be accessed from all machine with the same network. Do note also for me I need to run visual studio as admin as well. It may not be true for your case.