# Is there any other way to allow other devices on the same network to access IIS Express on a development machine?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

Today I found Conveyor with the following quoted from [its site](https://conveyor.cloud/Home/About).

> Conveyor is a Visual Studio extension, designed to take the hassle out of testing your application across devices. Created by Keyoti Inc., Conveyor allows developers to access the Visual Studio development server from devices across the network as well as remotely over the internet (beta).

## Question

Is there any other way to allow other devices on the same network to access IIS Express on a development machine but without using Conveyor?

Answer (score 1):

Educated guess: Same as with IIS, but you'll have to make manual settings. Open the port you want in your firewall. Make your machine visible on the network.

Also add this to you applicationhost.config:

```
<bindings>
  <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:*" />
</bindings>
```

Otherwise [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438322/4364057) looks very helpful.