# How to run the C# application from Visual Studio which can be accessed by 'https://{my ip address}:aport'

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I have a  ASP.NET C# application and I am able to run it locally on my machine.  I see it is IIS Express is hosting my application.

I can access it using 'https://localhost:4374'.

But when I look up my ip address of my machine and then go
https://{my ip address}:4374'.
I get an error saying 'Bad Request - Invalid Host name'

Can you please tell me how can I configure  ASP.NET C# application so that I can use it using  https://{my ip address}:4374?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure IIS Express for external access to VS2010 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433786/configure-iis-express-for-external-access-to-vs2010-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st solution:

Steps:

Open command prompt as administrator

Type the following:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress (YourIPAddress)
```

That's it. You should get:

```
IP address successfully added
```

2nd solution:

Steps:

1. Search for IISExpress on your computer
2. Open config/applicationhost.config file
3. Search for localhost and replace with (YourIPAddress)

Comment: Thanks. I tryed your solution #1 and I see 'IP 10.0.0.47 successfully added'. But when I go to https:10.0.0.47:44347, I see get bad host name

Comment: I also try your #2, I change the config/applicationhost.config file in my .vs directory. I replace localhost with my ip address. But after I re-run my app in VS, i can't load either https://localhost:mport or https:myipaddress:myport

Comment: Try to run the VS as an **Administrator** and set the applicationhost.config file like this `<ip-address>:<port>:<host-name>`
You can leave the ip-address and host-name empty in order for IIS-Express to listen on every IP and hostnames, like: `:44347:`